# Calculate $\Box w$ for $w(t,x):=g(v\cdot x-tc),\: (t,x)\in\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^m$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, laplacian

> Calculate $\Box w$ for $w(t,x):=g(v\cdot x-tc),\: (t,x)\in\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^m$ with $g\in C^2(\Bbb R)$, $c>0$ and $v\in\mathrm S^{m-1}$.

Here $\Box$ is the wave operator, defined by $\Box u(t,x):=\partial^2_t u(t,x)-\Delta_x u(t,x)$ and $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator. What I did was

$$\partial^2_t w(t,x)=c^2 \partial^2_t g(v\cdot x-tc)$$

$$\partial_{x_j} w(t,x)=v_j\partial_{x_j}g(v\cdot x-tc)\implies \partial^2_{x_j} w(t,x)=v_j^2\partial^2_{x_j}g(v\cdot x-tc)$$

Consequently

$$\Box w(t,x)=c^2\partial^2_t g(v\cdot x-tc)-\sum_{j=1}^mv_j^2\partial^2_{x_j}g(v\cdot x-tc)\tag1$$

so I dont get the point of this exercise, so my question is: can be $(1)$ simplified? I did the exercise correctly? I dont used the fact that $v\in\mathrm S^{m-1}$. The negative element of the RHS seems a weighted laplacian but I dont see that it can be simplified in any way.

I would be glad if some one can confirm that this was calculated correctly and if $(1)$ can be simplified further, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second line, you wrote $\partial_{x_j}w(t,x) =v_j\partial_{x_j}g(x\cdot v-tc),$ but that makes no sense because $g\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$. In other words, you are talking about partials of a single variable function.

Other than that, there is nothing wrong with the solution and once you correct it, you will get a slightly simpler expression.

Comment: mmm... however fixing $t$ and every $x_k$ except some $x_j$ if $g$ is differentiable respect to $t$ it is also respect to any $x_j$, that is $g$ is one real variable respect to $t$ and also respect to any $x_j$.

Comment: @ but that is not $g$ itself. Think about this. Say $h(t) =t^2$ and consider $h_x(x+y).$ You can calculate this directly and find $h_x(x+y) = 2x+2y.$ But symbolically this is equal to $\dfrac{d}{dt}\Big(h(t)\Big)(x+y).$ Now see what I am saying?

Comment: I see what you says but I dont follow what you want to mean in this context.

Comment: I am saying all of $\partial_{x_j}^2w(t,x)$ are simply $v_j^2g''(v\cdot x -tc)$

Comment: lol... I didnt knew this magic! :p Yes, by definition they are the same.